# Plots not loading in R console, using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, rstudio

Whenever I run code chunks containing plots within my project, it fails to load but doesn't display any error message, as if the console is frozen and then eventually times out. I have ran this code script 20 times or more and it all worked fine, but now for some reason unknown it just won't work.

I have tried:

- Restarting R
- Reinstalling R
- Updating and installing packages again
- Running different Rmd's/projects which have been run before, (they don't work either)

Any other code chunk will execute fine and other packages all seem to be operating as usual. I am currently running the latest Rstudio 4.1.3 build 492.

Here is my code anyway:

```
budget_revenue <- ggplot(data = filtered_movies2) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = budget, y = revenue, colour = genre_1)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ genre_1, nrow = 2) +
  labs(title = "Budget and Revenue by Genre", x = "Movie Budget", y = "Gross Revenue") +
  scale_y_continuous("Gross Revenue", 
                       breaks = scales::breaks_extended(8),
                       labels = scales::label_dollar()) + 
  scale_x_continuous("Movie Budget",
                     breaks = scales::breaks_extended(5),
                     labels = scales::label_dollar()) +
  theme_minimal() +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
  
  
  budget_revenue +
    scale_colour_viridis_d()
```

Comment: A few questions—do plots render outside of RMD? If you run a .R script? If not, are you using a Mac? If yes, regular .R script plots work fine—what settings do you have in RStudio? In options, R Markdown, Basic, is 'Show equation and image previews:' set to 'inline'? What are the other settings?

Comment: Hi Kat, thanks for the reply - I tried running in an R script as I am using Mac, my R markdown settings are as follows; show document outline as default(no), soft wrap markdown files(yes), show inn document outline(sections only), show output in preview(viewer pane), show output inline for all R markdown documents(yes),  show equation and image previews(inline), evaluate chunks in directory(chunks), then both R notebooks setting are(yes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With closing down and rebooting my machine, it allowed for all updates and reinstallation's to take effect and the issue was solved.